# Чтение с файла и запись в массив с использованием функции

Tags: java

Пишу код, есть функция reading() которая принимает String filename и возвращает новое значение через глобальную переменную getCipher (char). Сама функция выглядит следующим образом:

```
      System.out.print("Text from file is:");
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\Desktop\\\\" + filename));

  int symbol = bufferedReader.read();
  while (symbol != -1) {  

  getCipher = (char) symbol;
  symbol = bufferedReader.read(); 

  System.out.print(getCipher);
}
  bufferedReader.close();

  return getCipher;
```

Теперь вопрос, получается данным способом с вывожу только последний элемент при чтении с файла, я также знаю что я могу использовать массив из char-элементов. Но проблема в нём что я не могу написать

```
getCipher[] = (char)symbol //невозможно , так как запись в массив происходит через циклы
```

Как я могу получить все символы и сразу записать их в массив?
Могу чего-то упускать и не знать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект `BufferedInputStream` имеет метод `readAllBytes()` через который можно получить длину байтов передаваемого потока. Этой длиной инициализируете массив и затем пробегаетесь по-байтово и заполняете массив значениями.

Пример:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileReader(new File("")));

char[] getCipher = new char[bis.readAllBytes().length];

int i = 0;
while (bis.available() > 0) {
    getCipher[i] = (char) bis.read();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Трудно будет использовать массив,так как изначально неизвестно размер.
Можете воспользоваться `ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();`
При каждом чтении добавить символ: `list.add((char)symbol)`

Comment: Размер всегда будет 26

Comment: тогда можно и массивом , только нужно ещё хранить изначально int index = 0; потом arr[index] = getCipher; index++;